# 2035 and 2059 error while connecting to MQ

Tags: c#, .net, ibm-mq

I'm totally new to MQ, and need advice. I'm trying to connect to MQ server and send some text message on a queue.

- I installed MQ on a server on an Administrator account.
- Created test queue manager, and queue
- Downloaded example named "SimplePut", and modified code a little bit

I got 2035 error. So I add credencialls:

```
properties.Add(MQC.USER_ID_PROPERTY, "Administrator");
properties.Add(MQC.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, "Password!");
```

And I got 2059 error. So i configured Channel SYSTEM.DEF.SVRCONN type.

Now I got 2035 again.

This is my code https://dotnetfiddle.net/TaZAVR

edit 05.07.18: My explorer looks like this: [image]

Comment: You need to add CHLAUTH rules. Following link provides details on create/modify CHLAUTH
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.adm.doc/q086630_.htm

Comment: Ok - I have 2059 again...

Comment: 2059(MQRC_Q_MGR_NOT_AVAILABLE)  has nothing to do with the authority.2059 usually indicates that the listener is not running or the queue manager is down or if the channel is not defined.

Comment: https://image.ibb.co/mETAMd/Bez_tytu_u.png

Comment: cannot open your image. You can add it as part of your question

Comment: @subbaraoc ok it is done.

Comment: what parameters have you provided while executing your SimplePut application.If you don't provide the "-l" option ,the default channel "SYSTEM.DEF.SVRCONN" will be considered. Paste the output of your sample execution as well

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174412/discussion-between-subbaraoc-and-capitan-planet).